# scrollview breaks autolayout trailing and leading space

Tags: ios, autolayout

I am trying to build something in autolayout but the scrollview makes in impossible to do anything.
i want an image at the top of the scrollview that that has the top and both sides constrained, and just have the aspect ration locked so the bottom can expand as needed. but when i put in everything and update it the view shrinks to a 1x1 box in the corner. I have also tried setting the trailing and leading space to the root view but that didnt work either. WTF

[image: Constraints on the scrollview to lock it to the edges]

[image: contraints on image to lock it to sides and top and aspect ratio]

[image: what happens when i update the frames]

Comment: it might be easier to this in code instead of IB

Comment: but this is just one example. i plan to have 10 other things in the scrollview. The correct answer cant be to layout everything manually, can it?

Comment: Obviously a matter of preference, but I find coding constraints manually to be much clearer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @sdgandhi pointed out, when using autolayout in a scrollview, at a minimum it must have constraints which allow it to work out its `contentSize`.

You can happily constrain your view to the top, left, right and bottom of the scrollview. This tells the scrollview that the scrollable area should be equal to the size of that view (but does not force the view to be any size).

It looks to me that what you want to do is to force the width of the imageview to be the width of the screen. In which case you can constrain the imageview width to be that of the view which contains the scrollview (if your view controller's view is the scrollview, then you should instead have a normal `UIView` as the view controller's view and add the scrollview to it, constraining the scrollview to the top, left, right and bottom of it). This forces your imageview to be as wide as the screen, and if the `contentMode` is set to maintain aspect ratio, it will attempt to make its height the appropriate height for the image at that width which, in turn, will tell the scrollview what its scrollable area should be.

Comment: i have already tried assigning the left and right constraints to the view that contains the scrollview. it didnt do anything

Comment: Try using a width constraint when constraining to the container view, rather than left and right constraints — if you use left and right constraints you are basically disabling the scrollview (like using absolute positioning, if you are familiar with CSS). You constrain the imageview left and right to the scrollview's (which allows it to know where to start and end its content) and the imageview width to the container view width, which forces the imageview width, and thus allows the scrollview to know how wide its content is. And don't forget to constrain to the bottom of the scrollview.

Comment: Oh man finally we are getting somewhere. setting the width of the view to the width of the uiscrollview allowed it to do what i want it. Thank you so much i have banging my head over this for more than i would like to admit

Comment: Glad you got it sorted! Autolayout is pretty hard to get your head around, especially with regards scrollviews.

Answer (score 2):

To use autolayout in a scroll view, you must have constraints to each edge of the scrollview (including the bottom). **The reason is that scrollviews need to know their content size.**

With your constraints set up the way they are, the scroll view does not know it's content size.

In addition, right now all you're telling autolayout is that you want a imageview with a certain ratio. If this was outside a scroll view, it would be okay because the top and side pins would give it enough information to size itself. But because of the nature of a scroll view it needs more information. You can add width and height constraints and set their priorities low, or mark them as placeholders, **but you need to give the autolayout engine more information for it to calculate layout**.

See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2154/_index.html for a more in depth technical discussion of autolayout in `UIScrollView`

Comment: Even having one view and just set all contraints on all sides to 0 still makes it 1x1

Comment: Hmm, oh! You're setting an aspect ratio constraint, but no actual width and height constraints! You should set actual width and height constraints in addition to the aspect ratio constraint, this will let the scroll view actually know what it's content size is.

Comment: but it i set a hardcoded width and height whats the point of autolayout. then it wont look good on all but 1 phone

Comment: Yes, but right now all you're telling autolayout is that you want a imageview with a certain ratio. If this was outside a scroll view, it would be okay because the top and side pins would give it enough information to size itself. But because of the nature of a scroll view it needs more information. You can add width and height constraints and set their priorities low, or mark them as placeholders, but you need to give the autolayout engine more information for it to calculate layout.

Comment: that doesnt work either. i set everything and then only marked the width as a place holder, so it looks good in storyboard, but as soon as i run it returns back to the corner like before on the iphone

Comment: Try giving it a `greater than` or `greater than equal to` constraint for width.